# electron browserwindow useContentSize doesn't work

Tags: electron

When I create a BrowserWindow in electron, I want use the html size as the BrowserWindow  size instead of assigning width and height to it. So I set 'useContentSize:true', but the browserwindow size is default 800*600, it seems useContentSize doesn't work, does someone meet this problem?

here is my code of creating BrowserWindow

```
   

      var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({   
        frame: false,
        show: false,
        useContentSize: true
      })
```

and this is the html page for BrowserWindow to load

```
     

    body {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: red;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }      
    div {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: green;
        -webkit-app-region: drag;
    }
```

so when I use 'useContentSize: true', the BrowserWindow  should be 300*300,
 but the BrowserWindow is actually 800*600

and there is a screenshot

[electron browserwindow 'useContentSize:true'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acI3i.png)

Comment: Share code so that someone can go through.

Comment: @illiteratewriter I have updated with code, could you help to check?

Comment: No, useContentSize does not mean the size of the window would be equal to contentSize. It means the size of the webpage would be equal to width and height specified.

Comment: @shashi thanks, so we have to specific the width and height of the BrowserWindow when we create it, otherwise the width and height will be the default 800*600